# Angular 7 Http Calls with swagger client

Tags: angular, swagger, angular-httpclient

I am trying to make a service call from the angular app to a REST Service. The rest service is working fine. When I try to call the service from Angular, I don't see a call on the network tab too. I am missing something really basic. But I can't find what it is.
here is my swagger

```
/* tslint:disable */
//----------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Generated using the NSwag toolchain v11.17.19.0 (NJsonSchema v9.10.58.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0.0)) (http://NSwag.org)
// </auto-generated>
//----------------------
import { mergeMap as _observableMergeMap, catchError as _observableCatch } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, from as _observableFrom, throwError as _observableThrow, of as _observableOf } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable, Inject, Optional, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse, HttpResponseBase } from '@angular/common/http';

    export class ValuesClient {
        private http: HttpClient;
        private baseUrl: string;
        protected jsonParseReviver: ((key: string, value: any) => any) | undefined = undefined;
    constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) http: HttpClient, @Optional() @Inject(API_BASE_URL) baseUrl?: string) {
        this.http = http;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl ? baseUrl : "http://localhost:63242/";
    }

    getAll(): Observable<string[] | null> {
        let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/Values";
        url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

        let options_ : any = {
            observe: "response",
            responseType: "blob",
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                "Content-Type": "application/json", 
                "Accept": "application/json"
            })
        };

        return this.http.request("get", url_, options_).pipe(_observableMergeMap((response_ : any) => {
            return this.processGetAll(response_);
        })).pipe(_observableCatch((response_: any) => {
            if (response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
                try {
                    return this.processGetAll(<any>response_);
                } catch (e) {
                    return <Observable<string[] | null>><any>_observableThrow(e);
                }
            } else
                return <Observable<string[] | null>><any>_observableThrow(response_);
        }));
    }

    protected processGetAll(response: HttpResponseBase): Observable<string[] | null> {
        const status = response.status;
        const responseBlob = 
            response instanceof HttpResponse ? response.body : 
            (<any>response).error instanceof Blob ? (<any>response).error : undefined;

        let _headers: any = {}; if (response.headers) { for (let key of response.headers.keys()) { _headers[key] = response.headers.get(key); }};
        if (status === 200) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
            let result200: any = null;
            let resultData200 = _responseText === "" ? null : JSON.parse(_responseText, this.jsonParseReviver);
            if (resultData200 && resultData200.constructor === Array) {
                result200 = [];
                for (let item of resultData200)
                    result200.push(item);
            }
            return _observableOf(result200);
            }));
        } else if (status !== 200 && status !== 204) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
            return throwException("An unexpected server error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers);
            }));
        }
        return _observableOf<string[] | null>(<any>null);
    }

    get(id: number): Observable<string | null> {
        let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/Values/{id}";
        if (id === undefined || id === null)
            throw new Error("The parameter 'id' must be defined.");
        url_ = url_.replace("{id}", encodeURIComponent("" + id)); 
        url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

        let options_ : any = {
            observe: "response",
            responseType: "blob",
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                "Content-Type": "application/json", 
                "Accept": "application/json"
            })
        };

        return this.http.request("get", url_, options_).pipe(_observableMergeMap((response_ : any) => {
            return this.processGet(response_);
        })).pipe(_observableCatch((response_: any) => {
            if (response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
                try {
                    return this.processGet(<any>response_);
                } catch (e) {
                    return <Observable<string | null>><any>_observableThrow(e);
                }
            } else
                return <Observable<string | null>><any>_observableThrow(response_);
        }));
    }

    protected processGet(response: HttpResponseBase): Observable<string | null> {
        const status = response.status;
        const responseBlob = 
            response instanceof HttpResponse ? response.body : 
            (<any>response).error instanceof Blob ? (<any>response).error : undefined;

        let _headers: any = {}; if (response.headers) { for (let key of response.headers.keys()) { _headers[key] = response.headers.get(key); }};
        if (status === 200) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
            let result200: any = null;
            let resultData200 = _responseText === "" ? null : JSON.parse(_responseText, this.jsonParseReviver);
            result200 = resultData200 !== undefined ? resultData200 : <any>null;
            return _observableOf(result200);
            }));
        } else if (status !== 200 && status !== 204) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
            return throwException("An unexpected server error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers);
            }));
        }
        return _observableOf<string | null>(<any>null);
    }
}


    export class SwaggerException extends Error {
        message: string;
        status: number; 
        response: string; 
        headers: { [key: string]: any; };
        result: any; 

    constructor(message: string, status: number, response: string, headers: { [key: string]: any; }, result: any) {
        super();

        this.message = message;
        this.status = status;
        this.response = response;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.result = result;
    }

    protected isSwaggerException = true;

    static isSwaggerException(obj: any): obj is SwaggerException {
        return obj.isSwaggerException === true;
    }
}

function throwException(message: string, status: number, response: string, headers: { [key: string]: any; }, result?: any): Observable<any> {
    if(result !== null && result !== undefined)
        return _observableThrow(result);
    else
        return _observableThrow(new SwaggerException(message, status, response, headers, null));
}

function blobToText(blob: any): Observable<string> {
    return new Observable<string>((observer: any) => {
        if (!blob) {
            observer.next("");
            observer.complete();
        } else {
            let reader = new FileReader(); 
            reader.onload = function() { 
                observer.next(this.result);
                observer.complete();
            }
            reader.readAsText(blob); 
        }
    });
}`
```

I am using this client and making a call in my component and using it like this

```
this.valuesClient.get(24);
```

When I make the call, it is going to the swagger client and returnig and observable. But I don't see any call made to the URL. What am I missing?

Comment: `TL;DR`. I suspect you need to subscribe your method: `this.valuesClient.get(24).subscribe(data => {});`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either subscribe to the observable or pass it to an async pipe in your template.

```
this.valuesClient.get(24).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

To use in your template, you can automatically subscribe with the `async` pipe.

```
value$: Observable<string | null>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.value$ = this.valuesClient.get(24);
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<p>Value: {{ value$ | async }}</p>
```